# Get full path of files copied in to clipboard macos

Tags: macos, clipboard

I'm trying to read the full path of a files copied to the clipobard

After copying with [this script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339436/321333) files to the clipboard I ran this:

```
pbpaste > clipboard.txt
```

But all I got was the name of the files:

(clipboard.txt)

```
test.sh
test.py
myfolder
```

How can I get the full path so the output will be:

```
/path/path/test.sh
/path/path/test.py
/path/path/myfolder
```

Comment: Did you mean `cmd` instead off `ctrl`?

Comment: @0stone0 yes, my bad

Answer (score 3):

Instead off using <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd>, use <kbd>Cmd-Option-C</kbd>.

This will copy the **full** file path.

Using `pbpaste` will show the content of the clipbord with the full path.

Comment: Actually, I'm copying with [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339436/321333).

Comment: Then this is a whole different question. Why whould you say 'After copying with cmd+c files to the clipboard I ran this:' if you don't do it like that? Please edit the question to add **all** the details!